# fb page tab share with link inside

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create custom share button where user can go directly inside application (not in main page).

For example if client will share `https://example.com/Stories/Details/2` when someone will click on that link there must open my facebook application (page tabs app) and go in `Stories/Details/2` and **NOT** directly `https://example.com/Stories/Details/2`.

my code is:

```
$(".fbShare").on('click', function () {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: title,
            link: 'https://www.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/app/?sk=app_[APPLICATION-ID]&app_data=https://example.com/Stories/Details/2'
            caption: '',
            description: desc
        }, function (response) { });
    });
```

What's wrong?

`link: 'https://www.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/app/?sk=app_[APPLICATION-ID]&app_data=/Stories/Details/2'`

not works as well

Comment: Almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/36716318/1427878 – are you using multiple accounts …?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?